# google map - jquery window problem

Tags: jquery, google-maps, infowindow, openinfowindowhtml

When i click on marker always show the same data... why?

code:

```
function load() 
{
  var dialog = $('<div>').dialog({autoOpen:false});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
  {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) 
  {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
    {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng
                  (
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
                  );
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                   ({
                       map: map,
                       position: point,
                       icon: icon.icon,
                       shadow: icon.shadow
                   });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
     {
         dialog.html(html).dialog('open');
     });
    }
 });
```

}

Comment: How does infowindow associate with dialog? I see you create an InfoWindow but you never do anything with it. And then in the event listener where I'd expect to see InfoWindow code I see dialog. What's the relationship?

Comment: No, i dont want to see infowindow. i want to see jquery window (dialog) insted of infowindow but in jquery dialog i see the same data. Please see on http://kuponik.adriamart.com/davidimo.html

Comment: There is no marker on map from [link you posted](http://kuponik.adriamart.com/davidimo.html) in last comment.

Comment: please look again becouse is marker on serbia, belgrade and i dont center lat,lng on that... just zoom out map.

Comment: @adria:  Western US and Eastern Europe; you can't get any further apart than that!  LOL... ok I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1st change

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {...});
```

to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', dial(html));
```

2nd add the following function:

```
 function dial(html){
 return function(){
 dialog = $('<div>').dialog({autoOpen:false});
 dialog.html(html).dialog('open');
 }
 }
```

Hope it helps

K

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines...

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
```

to these...

```
var marker;
marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker

google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function()
```

Comment: I think it will work only if 'var marker' is moved out of the "for" loop

Comment: It's not problem with markers ... problem is window that show the same data for all markers...

Comment: @adria:   I realize it's not a marker problem but the same dialog text was being applied to all markers.